# Fatal error C1804. cannot read type library file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, typelib, tlbimp

I have a c++ project that is importing two .tlbs in a header file.

```
#import "..\bin\derived.tlb" named_guids raw_interfaces_only
#import "..\bin\base.tlb"  named_guids raw_interfaces_only
```

Now `derived.tlb` is dependent on base.tlb. There are base classes in `base.tlb` that classes in `derived.tlb` are based on.

When I compile, I get

> "fatal error c1084: cannot read type library file '..\derived.tlb': Error loading type library/DLL."

Now it's complaining about `derived.tlb` but the problem seems to really be in not being able to find `base.tlb`.

`base.tlb` comes from a `C# Com interop` project.  If I check the "register for com interop" in the build tab of the c# project, this problem goes away in the c++ project.  But I don't want to register it. This gets built on a build machine which shouldn't have anything registered on it.  So I create the `.tlb` with a post build step to `tlbexport`.

The `tlb` gets created in the correct folder but it appears that without the registration, `#import` can't find the `base.tlb` when importing `derived.tlb`.

I see in process monitor, it's trying a hell of a lot of places to find `base.tlb` but not the correct folder that equates to `..\bin\`.

What can I do to get it searching in the right place?  Adding an entry for it in "Additional Include Directories" in the c++ project doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Maybe I just need to copy the appropriate tlbs to a directory I'm sure the c++ code will be able to reach it? I can see from proc monitor all the places it's trying. I can just select one of those directories to copy the tlb to with a prebuild step

Comment: Use the Additional Include Directories settings instead of ..\bin.  Don't import base.tlb

Comment: That's even better. Thanks!